# What is 'global symbol registry'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

```
var sym = Symbol();
```

is `window['sym']` which is already **global scope**.

But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Description) says:

> The above syntax using the `Symbol()` function **will not create** a global symbol that is available in your whole codebase. To create symbols **available across files and in a global scope-like environment**, use the methods `Symbol.for()` and `Symbol.keyFor()` to set and retrieve symbols from the global symbol registry.

`sym` is already in global scope in  a browser, with above declaration syntax.

What is global symbol registry?

Each html document is tied with `window` object.

So,
In a browser world, How does this scope of symbol availability across files/realms *different* from global scope(`window` object)?

Comment: So what's your question, why creating a global variable makes it a global variable, even when the value of the global variable is a symbol ?

Comment: @overexchange What do you mean by "actual value"? It's super unclear what you're expecting. `sym` is the value, there is nothing else to show.

Comment: loganfsmyth, that was with reference to some linked question, Ignore it.

Comment: See also [Symbol.for(string) in ECMAScript 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30984858/1048572)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> ```
> var sym = Symbol();
> ```
>
> is creating a new property `sym` in dictionary(`window`), which is in global scope, where value can be accessed as `window['sym']`.

Well, no. It does create a symbol and assigns it to a *local variable* named `sym`. Only if you are executing this code in the global scope (which you usually wouldn't, for modularity) it does create a property on the global object of your realm (js environment). Notice that this global object is not always `window` like in web pages, it depends on your environment.

> What is global symbol registry?

It's a registry (think: dictionary) for symbols that you can access via a string key. And "global" does in this case mean even *more global* than a global scope, the global symbol registry does span all realms of your engine. In a browser, the web page, an iframe, and web worker would all have their own realm with own global objects, but they could share symbols via this global registry.

And this sharing is exactly the purpose. If you'd otherwise put

```
var sym1 = Symbol("shared");

var sym2 = Symbol("shared");
```

in two places, then `sym1 !== sym2`. If you've got a shared object, using the symbol*s* as property keys would create two different properties. If however you do

```
var sym1 = Symbol.for("shared");

var sym2 = Symbol.for("shared");
```

then `sym1 === sym2` and when you use it you'll always get the same property.

See also [*Crossing realms with symbols* on 2ality](http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html#crossing-realms-with-symbols) and [*Symbols and why they're awesome*](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/#:%7E:text=Symbols%20are%20completely%20unique%E2%80%A6) for more examples, including the well-known symbols which are similarly global.

Comment: Is GlobalSymbolRegistry(GSR) physically different from `window` object? As JS engine of a browser maintains `window` object,  Who maintains GSR?

Comment: @overexchange: Yes, it's very different. It only contains strings as registry keys, and only symbols as values. The global object contains all kinds of properties. The global symbol registry is maintained by the JS engine. Notice that a JS engine does maintain *multiple* global environments/scopes/objects/`window`s; that's why is said the GSR is "more global".

Comment: Any article that talks more on multiple global_environments/scopes/objects/`window`s that is maintained by JS engine?

Comment: @overexchange: I didn't find anything specific, it's a well known fact that each web page has it's own global environment, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4857969/1048572). Except for the obvious security reasons, this is so that each page is stand-alone, and e.g. can be run in its own browser thread. The HTML5 spec also refers to [global environments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#javascript-global-environment) when it does define the [javascript processing model](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#definitions-0).

Comment: But I got one example from your [reference](http://2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html#crossing-realms-with-symbols). What more can I ask?

Answer (score 7):

The global symbol registry is just a convenient global repository for symbol instances. You could implement one yourself if you wanted to, but having such a repository built-in means that the runtime can use it as a place to publish symbol instances that have particular meaning for a given context.

In your own application, you can decide that some types of objects will have certain properties accessible via some symbol. All your code can find those symbols via `Symbol.for()`:

```
var SPECIAL_PROPERTY = Symbol.for("mySpecialProperty");
// ...
var specialVal = someObject[SPECIAL_PROPERTY];
```

Because the registry is global, that works regardless of scope or compilation unit.

By making the registry part of the runtime, an environment like Node.js can use the symbol mechanism to extend objects without fear of causing problems for legacy code. Like, if Node wanted to make it such that you could find out how much memory an object used, they could invent a symbol, put it in the registry, and document the registry key. Any code could then use that:

```
var objectSize = myObject[Symbol.for("memory_use")];
```

(That's totally made up; it might make no sense at all for Node to do that particular thing.) Because of the way symbols work as property keys, code that doesn't know about that won't experience any weird issues should the objects it manipulates suddenly start carrying around that extra property.

(Of course, the namespace of the symbol registry itself is just a namespace, so collisions would have to be dealt with there in pretty much exactly the same way we deal with name collisions in the `window` object.)

Comment: Global scope is at  `window` object level. If a single html file includes multiple .js files thru script tag. Environment created by multiple .js files comes under same single `window` object. Am I correct? When you say across files(whole codebase), which scope are we talking about? Am still not clear.

Comment: @overexchange it's at `window` object level *in a browser*. There are other JavaScript environments that have no `window` object. But yes, all JavaScript code in the context of a web page have access to the same `window` object. The scope of the global symbol registry is simply the same scope as that of the global `Symbol()` function itself.

Comment: Is *global symbol registry*(GSR) part of JS engine that is physically different from `window` object? If GSR is at same scope of `window` object, then why do we require GSR?

Comment: Also, in most modular JS code (including Node), the top-level scope of the file is the module scope, not the global scope, so your `var sym` example would not be global.

Answer (score 1):

Global symbol registry exists across all iframes in a window. (As symbols can't be passed across workers, there's no observable concept of it being identical across workers, barring the existence of sidechannel inspections, eg by [memory probing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997034/are-es6-global-symbols-garbage-collected/40016587#comment79447932_40016587).)

```
<script>
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'))
.src=`javascript:
  alert(parent.Symbol===Symbol) /*false*/
  ,alert(parent.Symbol.for('a') === Symbol.for('a')) //true
`
</script>
```

`Symbol.for` is not much different from implementing your own cache using an object reference. It's merely in-built and thus more convenient. Instead of `Symbol.for('a')`, you can simply do:

```
obj['a']? obj['a'] : obj['a'] = Symbol()
```

.and maintain a ref to `obj`.

In fact, since javascript does not provide an API to remove symbols in the global registry, its beneficial to do it the manual-caching way if you need to manually manage the memory of the registry.