# How are Symbols implemented in JavaScript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently learned about Symbols in JavaScript ES6, and I was very curious about how it is implemented underneath the hood.

Specifically, I am curious about how Symbols are implemented to achieve uniqueness:

```
a = Symbol('key')
b = Symbol('key')
a !== b // true
```

But can also achieve its `for` functionality:

```
a = Symbol.for('key')
b = Symbol.for('key')
a === b // true
```

Can anyone shed some light on how this is implemented underneath the hood?

I read the MDN documentation, but it mainly described the interface, rather than the implementation.

Comment: Implementation details depend on the implementation, not the language.

Comment: Most likely the first uses a randomly generated ID or one based on the memory location, while the second uses some kind of hash of the string passed in.

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-symbol-objects

Answer (score 0):

> I am curious about how Symbols are implemented to achieve uniqueness

Just like objects: when you create a new instance, it has its own [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming)).

> Can anyone shed some light on how `for` is implemented underneath the hood?

It's basically a `Map` that caches the created symbols by name. It's called the [global symbol registry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31897015/1048572).