# Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Given a symbol

```
const title = Symbol('Csv column title');
```

representing a key of an object and the text of a header in a table. I thought I could setup the headers like so

```
const tableHeaders: { key: string }[] = [{ key: title }];
```

but unfortunately I get the errors

> Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)

and

> TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

It seems [Symbol.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toString) is not what I'm looking for since `Symbol('title').toString()` returns `"Symbol(title)"`.

How can I use the symbol as a string?

Comment: Why is it even a symbol in the first place? It seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to utilise the global symbol registry [¹](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#shared_symbols_in_the_global_symbol_registry) [²](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897015/what-is-global-symbol-registry) to achieve this:

```
const title = Symbol.for('Csv column title');

const tableHeaders: { key: string }[] = [{ key: Symbol.keyFor(title)! }];
```

If you need to retrive the symbol again you can use `Symbol.for(tableHeaders[0].key)` which should get the same symbol from the registry.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `keyof` and `typeof` like so :

```
const title = Symbol('Csv column title');

const tableHeaders: { [key in keyof typeof title]: string }[] = [{ [title]: 'Title' }];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This code didn't compile in the TS playground ( v4.9.5 ) and I don't think that this is what I'm looking for. The object should be similiar to `{ key: title }`